# Query minus problems?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is not returning the expected amount of records
the first part returns 50.000 records
the second part (below the minus) returns 30.000
so as conclusion my minus should return 20.000 records.
only this is not happening more records are removed 21.000.

-- edit --
the count returns more rows that expected, these returned records will in a later step be removed.

Anyone suggestions?

```
-- select count(*) from (
 SELECT        
    loc.ITEM, 
            loc.loc
            FROM ITEM_LOC loc
    WHERE LOC NOT IN(101,104,107,115,116,117)
    and loc.status = 'A' 
    and primary_supp in (select supplier from item_supplier where supp_discontinue_date >= sysdate) 
   --        );
minus
 --; select count(*) from (
 select distinct item, store from (
  SELECT        
            siv.ITEM,
            sto.store 
            FROM DC_CCN190_SID_VTB siv
            JOIN DC_STORE_RANGING str ON siv.dpac = str.dpac
    join store sto on sto.store_name_secondary = cast(str.loc as varchar2(150 byte))
    where sto.store_close_date >= sysdate 
        union
            SELECT 
    pim.ITEM,
            sto.store
            FROM dc_pim_export_vert PIM
            JOIN DC_STORE_RANGING str ON PIM.dpac = str.dpac
    join store sto on sto.store_name_secondary = cast(str.loc as varchar2(150 byte))
    where PIM.artikel_type_lms = 'D1'
    and sto.store_close_date >= sysdate 
    )
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**count returns 50.000**

```
  select count(*) from (
 SELECT        
    loc.ITEM, 
            loc.loc
            FROM ITEM_LOC loc
    WHERE LOC NOT IN(101,104,107,115,116,117)
    and loc.status = 'A' 
    and primary_supp in (select supplier from item_supplier where supp_discontinue_date >= sysdate));
```

**count returns 30.000**

```
select count(*) from (
 select distinct item, store from (
  SELECT        
            siv.ITEM,
            sto.store 
            FROM DC_CCN190_SID_VTB siv
            JOIN DC_STORE_RANGING str ON siv.dpac = str.dpac
    join store sto on sto.store_name_secondary = cast(str.loc as varchar2(150 byte))
    where sto.store_close_date >= sysdate 
        union
            SELECT 
    pim.ITEM,
            sto.store
            FROM dc_pim_export_vert PIM
            JOIN DC_STORE_RANGING str ON PIM.dpac = str.dpac
    join store sto on sto.store_name_secondary = cast(str.loc as varchar2(150 byte))
    where PIM.artikel_type_lms = 'D1'
    and sto.store_close_date >= sysdate 
    );
```

***So the minus should return 20.000 right?***

Comment: `MINUS`, as `UNION`, removes duplicates from its output. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: I don't understand your maths though. If more records are being removed why would it return a higher number of rows? Did you get these the wrong way round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A = 50000. B = 30000. A - B = 21000. What is B - A? I'm expecting 1000. That is, there are 1000 records in B that are not included in A. In a simple case,

A returns 4 records
Jim
Bob
Mary
Samantha

B returns 3 records
Bob
Mary
Josephine

A - B returns 2 records: 
Jim
Samantha

B - A returns 1 record:
Josephine

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
select count(*)
```

in both queries and compare the result with

```
select distinct count(*)
```

There should be a difference!

---

From [HERE](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Minus), "Additionally, if there are two identical rows in table_A, and that same row exists in table_B, BOTH rows from table_A will be removed from the result set."

---

---

**If there's no difference, then only one explanation:**

> MINUS is a SQL set operation that selects elements from the first
> table and then removes rows that are also returned by the second
> SELECT statement.

**Not all rows from the second second are present in the first one.**

Comment: Tried the distinct but still returned 21.000 records instead of 20.000.

Comment: @Eve offcourse. I just said to use distinct and see if the total number is different without using it. For this, you shouldn't make the `MINUS`. If the total numbers are different, that's because you have duplicate values. If so, the `MINUS` will remove them and that's why there as more records deleted.

Comment: as two separate queries the queries are returning the "expected" amount of records and then together with the minus the query returns 1.000 more records. The distinct has already been done because the first part doesn't have any duplicates

Comment: As two separate queries, the `select count(*)` gives different results from `select distinct count(*)` ?

Comment: But that wouldn't explain why more records are return, that would mean 19.000 instead of 21.000. I just guessing here

Comment: 50000-30000 = 20000. If it's returning 21000 it means that 1000 records from 50000 are not present in the 30000.

Comment: `select distinct count(*)` means do the count, then apply distinct to that result set.  Since you're not grouping, the result set consists of one row, so the distinct operation is meaningless.  To count the number of distinct values, you need to do something like `select count(*) from (select distinct col1, col2 from table_name)`